# Win 7 x64 explorer.exe stops responding on copy/paste

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, copy-paste

Few months ago I changed my Win7 orb using [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-start-button-changer-released) software. But it changed only the `explorer.exe` in `C:\Windows`. To solve that, I copied `explorer.exe` from there to `C:\Windows\system32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (Probably a bad idea).

Things were working fine until a few days ago, it started giving me problems while copying. Sometimes, when I copy/paste, It works fine but sometimes it stays on that dialog box which looks like it is doing pre-copying things like counting number of files/file size etc. But its not. It stays on that screen forever. Now if I try to close it, title changes to `cancelling` but rest stays the same.

If I try to close it too many times, `explorer.exe` crashes. And its not related to file-size. It may crash for 4Mb file and work fine for 10Gb file but some other time, it'll do the opposite.

**Is there any way to reset my `explorer.exe`** and **Is this because of `explorer.exe` or something else**

PS: I forgot to take backup of `explorer.exe`.

PS2: I didn't install any software or downloaded anything that could harm my computer.

**EDIT**

I tried System Restore and `SFC /scannow` but they didn't help.

Comment: What a mess. I'd re-image my PC in this situation. I keep a full image of my primary Windows 7 system which I can re-deploy in 15 minutes using my "Todo Backup" imaging DVD. The install I've setup redirects my desktop, My Documents etc. to my "D" drive on a RAID 1 mirror I have for my data partiton- so only a 19GB image of Windows 7 and applications gets re-loaded. It's blazing fast as my system drive is SSD (system image backup kept on the mirror). Every time I see the tiniest glitch (or boot times go over 25 seconds) I just nuke and re-image while I have a glass of wine!

Comment: Open an elevated command prompt and run `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that. I did it but it didn't help

Comment: @downvoter Please specify the reason for downvote

Comment: until you figure it out, try using teracopy for copy/paste operations and see if the problem persists..

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to try:

- Run a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/system-restore) and go back to a point before you changed it.
- Try running an `sfc` ([System File Check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)) and hope it puts Explorer back the way it should be.
- Get a copy of the version(s) of Explorer.exe from another (working) install of Windows 7 64-bit.

You may also want to run some [memory tests](http://www.memtest.org/), and some [disk checks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried all of those, but it didn't help. SFC said that system has no problems. I don't have access to any other win7. I do have Win7 DVD, will that be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to extract files from windows DVD.
Refer this article: http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/

Before you go ahead, a note of caution:

1. Make sure it is the same DVD from which your current windows installation was created.
2. Take a backup before replacing any file.

**PS:** Run the orb changer tool gain. It has an option to restore the start logo which basically restores original explorer.exe which is backed up by the tool at the time it changes the start orb.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. In our case we uninstalled a program called mywinlocker and everything returned to normal.